# Query vars in url (wordpress) work fine when page loaded directly, but fail on ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I've a little issue, and I couldn't find anything about it... I'm in deadlock.

So I've wp page that contains normal loop, if I call this file directly in browser all works fine, and I can even use query-vars such as: http://domain.com/blog/wp-content/themes/wovies-bones/getmovies.php?actor=x And it works fine, I get single post that has custom taxonomy actor = x.

But when I try to load same using ajax, it behaves differently and ignoring my get request returns all posts...

Any ideas what is happening?

ajax-jquery part:

```
$.ajax({
  url: templatePath + "getmovies.php",
  type: "GET",
  data: filters_get,
  cache: false,
  success: function (data){
    console.dir(data);
  }
});
```

And php part:

```
    /* Define these, So that WP functions work inside this file */
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');


?>






    <div id="container">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="movie">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php
                    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail('homepage-preview');}
                    else {echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/default-poster.jpg" />';}
                ?>
                <p class="comments"><?php comments_number('0 review','1 review','% reviews'); ?></p>
                <div class="description">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <!-- No movies found -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- End #container -->
```

filters_get looks like this: ?actor=x&

Answer (score 0):

This way, you just load WordPress and run your own PHP file. Basicaly, I think you should redefine your WP_Query like this :

```
/*Define these, So that WP functions work inside this file */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

global $wp_query;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'my_tax'    => $_GET['my_tax']
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

// Your template stuff
```

And if you're using AJAX to get your posts, you'd better use a hooked function as it is described in [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_my_cpt', 'get_my_cpt');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_cptn', 'get_my_cpt');

function get_my_cpt() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
        'my_tax'    => $_GET['my_tax']
    );

    $cpts = get_posts($args);

    if(empty($cpts)) {
        _e('No custom post to show');
        exit;
    }

    foreach($cpts as $cpt) {
        // Do you stuff to display your custom posts
    }

}
```

Then you will have to use this kind of url in your AJAX call : http://www.domain.tld/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_my_cpt&my_tax=keyword